# How disable hyphenation but keep my hyphenation rules

Tags: hyphenation

I have text and my own hyphenation table

```
\hyphenation{al-a ko-ta mie-ć mu-si}
```

How do I disable hyphenation and I still use my own hyphenation?
I'm not only add hyphenation. I must DELETE all hyphenation and AFTER add my own.

Maybe I must create my own hyphenation file? New definition language?

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article} 
\usepackage{fontspec} 
\usepackage{polyglossia} 
\setotherlanguage{polish} 
\begin{document} 

\hyphenation{al-a ko-ta mie-ć mu-si} 

Tu sa inne zdania i nawet bardzo długaśne. Łojej, Ala żółtego kota mieć musi, a nie żabę.

\end{document}
```

I compile with `xelatex`, but my question is for any tex/latex/lualatex etc –

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: It's not clear why you'd want to override all the hyphenation patterns.

Comment: Because i use specyfic word, and polish,english hyphen is wrong. I need use only my own hyphenation, no from system

Answer (score 5):

If your language is not Polish, then don't load the language.

Just activate `nohyphenation` and you're done. In the example, `\parbox{0pt}` forces TeX to hyphenate as much as possible.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\begin{document}
\hyphenrules{nohyphenation}
\hyphenation{al-a ko-ta mie-ć mu-si}
\lefthyphenmin=1 \righthyphenmin=1

\parbox{0pt}{Tu sa inne zdania i nawet bardzo długaśne.
Łojej, Ala żółtego kota mieć musi, a nie żabę.}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you need to support other languages, here's the scheme:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O} % a font with support for Greek

\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{polish}
\setotherlanguage{greek}

\newenvironment{fantasylanguage}
 {\hyphenrules{nohyphenation}\lefthyphenmin=1 \righthyphenmin=1 }
 {}

\begin{hyphenrules}{nohyphenation}
\hyphenation{al-a ko-ta mie-ć mu-si}
\end{hyphenrules}

\begin{document}

\begin{fantasylanguage}
\parbox{0pt}{\hspace{0pt}Łojej, Ala żółtego kota mieć musi, a nie żabę.}
\end{fantasylanguage}

\medskip

\begin{greek}
θaλb εcπdδ
\end{greek}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If I disable lang (i use 3) all characters no latin disapears ;( I must use characters outside latin set. I use greek letters put θaλb εcπdδ and

Comment: @bardzo The font you're using doesn't support Greek; it has nothing to do with hyphenation. Please, add information to your question, or open a new one; I answered the question as is.

Comment: My font have greek chars. Yours answer is not working

Comment: @bardzo I ***can't*** know what font you're using; your example has no font choice, so Latin Modern is selected, which doesn't support Greek. Please, be careful before saying “your answer is not working”, which is definitely false.

Comment: ok, meybe You are right, I check it

Comment: Yes, You are right,I'm wrong. All working ok.